# Oracle birthday column regex constrain violated

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want all my dates in my database in the following yyyy-mm-dd date format. For example, '2020-05-28'. But this doesn't seem to work as I thought it would when I insert a date into my User table which contains the birthday column.

Here's my birthday column constraint :

```
birthday DATE NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(birthday , '\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*')),
```

I get the following error when I try to insert : '2020-05-28' or any other date for that matter :

```
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check

*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrongly interpreting the concept of the `DATE` datatype. Probably, you are mixing the *display format* of dates (the value that you see when you  display a `date`  value), and their *internal representation*.

A `date` is just that: a date. It is stored internally in some database specific format, that you don't need to worry about. So there is no need for a check constraint to control the format.

Whenever you need to *display* date, you can use function `to_char()` to format it as a string, like:

```
to_char(birthday, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

You can also set session parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` so all dates are automatically formated in a given format when displayed:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
```